# Are server security restrictions causing issues with allow_url_fopen & allow_url_include

Tags: php, security, google-maps-api-3

I am "stuck" in the middle between my Apache web Host and my developer - guidance sought. I am not a competent developer - so please go easy on my in helping me with answers.

I have a page that does one of 2 things via API V3.27 :
1. Sends Lat, Lng to Google maps and displays Street View
2. Sends an Address to Google Maps and display Street View + save Lat, Lng, Pitch etc for future use.

Prior to my web host moving my site to a new server all was well. Now task 2 is failing with the following errors:

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/(domain)/public_html/functions.php on line 8

file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Pkwy,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043&sensor=false): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/(domain)/public_html/functions.php on line 8

My developer has attempted to enable allow_url_fopen & allow_url_include from cpanel without success.

Does the above indicate that the developer needs to make some code changes or is the issue related to one of the following security restrictions that my Web Host tells me is in place on my server (I cannot get them to tell me if the same restrictions applied to the old server).

"the following PHP functions are disabled globally"
exec, passthru, system, popen, show_source, proc_open, shell_exec, eval, ini_set

If any of the above restrictions are causing issues with Google Maps API, is it common or uncommon for web hosts to have such restrictions.

===
If the issues are actually due to restrictions on my server I will have to find a new web host ( lot of work to transfer site and SSL, but if the issues are due to the way the page has been coded, then I need to go back to my developer for code changes.

Any pointers or questions for clarification welcome.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I found this useful and I think this question does have a place on stack overflow but just needs to be reworded. 

ie. Here is my code: How can I do this without using file_get_contents as my host won't allow me to enable allow_url_fopen & allow_url_include.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `curl` and use:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Pkwy%2C%20Mountain%20View%2C%20CA%2094043&sensor=false");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    // use your $result response here what Google returns
    echo $result;
}

curl_close ($ch); // curl_errno must be before curl_close
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time in replying. I was unable to vote your reply UP, as I do not have enough reputation. It appears that the view of many on stackoverflow is "don't ask a question unless you are an expert" - as can be seen by the negative vote on this question and previous ones. Once again thanks for your help. I hope you will not mind more non expert questions. If the developer is requiring any of the following, is this bad coding, or are any of these always required for google maps API. allow_url_fopen, allow_url_include or ini_set?

Comment: Here is a small section form my code on functions.php  Is this in the right location where your code should replace existing code. I will not be trying myself, I just want to be able to point out to my developer where (if anywhere) he is not using the most appropriate code - I realsie I may not be giving enough or correct info for you to answer properly, but any advice would be appreciated

Comment: [code extract] function get_lat_long($address)
{

    $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);

    $json = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false");
    $json = json_decode($json);
 if(count($json->{'results'}) > 0)
 {
     $lat = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
     $long = $json->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
  $latlong=$lat.','.$long;

Comment: Thanks again, the quick solution was to move to a different web host, all worked ok. Developer has agreed to change code to use Curl, at some stage in the future.